# What needs to be done after deleting an item in a hash table built under opening addressing with linear probing

Tags: hash, hash-tables, assignment-problem

In some textbook problems, the problem asks me to insert a bunch of elements and remove a bunch of elements.

Insertion is done using linear probing, i.e. h = XmodR + I, when there is a collision, I just hop one item over until I find a good spot

But for deletion...do I just remove the item from the table? Is that all there is to it? Can someone inform me whether I should be reshuffling the existing items after the removal?

Attached is a sample of what kind of problem I'm describing
[image]

In the above problem, if I were to remove 58, is there anything else I need to do?

Comment: What do you think? If you just delete the item, would the other operations work? If so, this is all there is to it. Otherwise, see what needs to be done so that the other operations keep working.

Comment: @yuvalfilmus :( I have always done linear probing the same way I never thought about extra operation after deleting I don't know if I need to do anything extra

Comment: More generally, every data structure has *invariants* that ensure that all the operations work. After every operation that changes the state, we have make sure that the invariant is kept. Find out what invariants are needed for the hash table to work, and so if simple deletion violates them.

Comment: @yuvalfilmus Okay, so the solution would be to insert a flag or something. Some references suggest inserting -1. Hmm this operation is actually quite dangerous because you might need to actually delete a -1...intereseting